# Centralized master bib file with bibunits

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, bibunits

I saw here:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38290/69378 that

> You can reference central-bibliography.bib at an `absolute` or `relative` (preferred) location from within the \bibliography command:
>
> ```
> \bibliography{../references/central-bibliography}
> ```

I haven't been able to duplicate this behavior using `bibunits` and `\defaultbibliography{}`.  Is this impossible? Or have I have I hopefully missed something superficial?

The reason I am trying to implement a solution like this, is I am sharing a common bib and bst file (among many others; which are all under heavy development) with my collaborators, but to ensure everyone is working from the same up-to-date file, I have to put the path references in the tex code, because everyone is using a different method to compile the code.  I was hoping I could add a path to `\graphicspath{}` but they don't seem to communicate.  Unfortunately as well, a back trace `/../` is out of the question as everybody's path to the dropbox will be different.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage[numbers,square,comma,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{bibunits} 

\defaultbibliography{F:/Work/Dropbox/__.Bib Files To Merge/CombinedBibFile}% tried with and without quotes
\defaultbibliographystyle{F:/Work/Dropbox/__.Bib Files To Merge/IEEEtranNcustom}% removes URL additions 

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\section{\bibname}\markboth{\leftmark}{\bibname}}
\begin{bibunit}
Text with citation \cite{BIBTEX_KEY_HERE).

\putbib
\end{bibunit}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I welcome any more robust answers, but I have solved this issue by removing spaces from the file path.

I originally didn't think that was going to be successful, because I had tried (with no success)

1. adding quotation marks around the path
2. tried out the recommendation here:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27537/69378 
   but using `\detokenize{}` and replacing spaces with `~`.

Comment: You can also try adding \string before the tilde (~) when using the MS-DOS 8.3 file name format.